# Dialogflow slot filling problem with required parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, dialogflow-es

I'm creating a bot for a snack machine with Dialogflow, but I'm having a problem.
I have two types of entities:

- `simple-element` : objects with no type (chocolate, chips).
- `complex-element` : elements that have multiple types, like water (still or sparkling) and coffee (lungo, macchiato or americano).

I made two different intents for the two entities, `order.simple.element` and  `order.complex.element`.

In  `order.complex.element` I set as required parameters the number of elements and the element type itself, I would like to set as required also the complex element types, but only when the complex element is matched, which means to ask the user *How do you want the water? Still or Spark?* only when the entity is the *water*.

[Action and Parameters Dialogflow console image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6UG5.png)

I tried also with webhook calls but it doesn't work. Here my code using nodejs:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug';

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
    console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));
  
    function welcome (agent) {
      agent.add(`Welcome! What do you want?`);
    }
    function fallback (agent) {
      agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
      agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
    }

    function orderComplexElement(agent) {
        var complex_el = agent.parameters['complex-element'].toLowerCase();
        if (complex_el === 'water') {
            agent.add('How do you want it? Still or sparkling?');
            agent.add(new Suggestion('still'));
            agent.add(new Suggestion('sparkling'));
            
        } else if (complex_element === 'coffee') {
            agent.add('How do you want it? You can choose from americano, lungo and macchiato.');
        }
    }
    
    let intentMap = new Map();
    intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
    intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
    intentMap.set('order.complex.element.try', orderComplexElement);
    agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

How can I make complex element type as required based on the `complex-element` type?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to capture the user response for water-type and coffee-type and then save those parameters in your context. For example:

```
    var water-type = request.body.queryResult.queryText; // this captures the user input
    agent.context.set({ // saves the parameter to a context.
      name:'sessionvars', //you can use this context to capture all variables
      lifespan: 50, //context will be available for 50 conversational turns
      parameters: {
        'water-type': water-type
      }
    });
```